# Acces to parent's attribute from descendant

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have an XML file like this:

```
<reservation>
  <day name="monday">
    <slot number="1">
      <name>..</name>
      <description>..</description>
    </slot>
    <slot number="3">
      <name>..</name>
      <description>..</description>
    </slot>
  </day>
  <day name="friday">
    <slot number="4">
      <name>..</name>
      <description>..</description>
    </slot>
  </day>
</reservation>
```

And I need to write a LINQ query where I would have access to the `name` of day and the `slot` attributes and elements in one time.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it could be done in a better way, but:

```
string xml = @"<reservation>
    <day name=""monday"">
        <slot number=""1"">
            <name>name</name>
            <description>desc</description>
        </slot>
        <slot number=""3"">
            <name>..</name>
            <description>..</description>
        </slot>
    </day>
    <day name=""friday"">
        <slot number=""4"">
            <name>..</name>
            <description>..</description>
        </slot>
    </day>
    </reservation>";

var element = XElement.Parse(xml);

var res = from day in element.Elements("day")
          from slot in day.Elements()
          from slotName in slot.Elements("name")
          from slotDesc in slot.Elements("description")
          select new
          {
            Day = day.Attribute("name").Value, 
            Slot = slot.Attribute("number").Value,
            Name = slotName.Value,
            Desc = slotDesc.Value
          };
```

will produce this result:

```
Day    Slot Name Desc 
monday 1    name desc 
monday 3    ..   .. 
friday 4    ..   ..
```

Comment: It looked very good but it returns nothing, the res variable is empty..?

Comment: I copy-pasted my answer in a console application and it worked like expected. Consider that the return type is an IEnumerable of an anonymous type.

Comment: It was my fault, I was using XDocument instead XElement for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(/* ... */);

var slots =
   xDocument.Descendants("day")
            .SelectMany(day => day.Elements("slot")
                                  .Select(
                                    slot => new
                                      {
                                        DayName = day.Attribute("name").Value,
                                        Name = slot.Element("name").Value,
                                        Number = slot.Attribute("number").Value,
                                        //...
                                      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will suit you:

```
var slots = xelement.Descendants("slot")
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        Slot = e, Day = e.Parent
                    }).ToList();
```

You can further modify it to get only interesting attributes or elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `XObject` class has [a `Parent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so for a slot `s` you could do:

```
s.Parent.Attribute("name").Value
```

Though this is a bit hard to read – how do we know that `s.Parent` is a slot? You can just access all the information you need at the `day` level:

```
var days = xDocument.Descendants("day");
var allSlots = days.SelectMany(d => {
  // Your code here...
  var daySlots = d.Descendants("slot");
  return daySlots.Select(s => String.Format("{0} {1}",
                              d.Attribute("name").Value,
                              s.Attribute("number").Value));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var document =  XDocument.Load(xml);

var query = from stol in document.Descendants("slot")
             select new
                 {
                     Day = (string) stol.Ancestors().First().Attribute("name"),
                     Number = (int) stol.Attribute("number"),
                     Name = (string) stol.Descendants("name").SingleOrDefault(),
                     Description = (string) stol.Descendants("description").SingleOrDefault(),
                 };
```